# Problems with SRID 32717

Tags: qgis, postgis, srid

I'm new with GIS systems and I need to determine if a point is into a polygon, I'm using a shapefile with SRID 32717 and I have a list of points (long, lat). With QGIS I export the shapefile to a PostGIS database, and I'm using the st_contains function, this is my query:

```
select * from geo_data
where st_contains(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-78.480439 -0.179156)',32717))
```

I validate that the point is into a polygon, but the query does not return records.

You can download the shapefile from here:

http://www.inec.gob.ec/estadisticas/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=&func=startdown&id=1361&lang=es&TB_iframe=true&height=250&width=800

Answer (score 6, accepted):

epsg:32717 is a UTM projection in meters, not degrees, which [covers a thin strip from Ecuador down through Peru.](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-17s/)

You're telling it the point coordinates you have are in epsg:32717. But these seem to be longitude and latitude, consistent with Ecuador.

That parameter **doesn't project data** for you. You're just tagging the coordinates with that CRS. To reproject, you need to use **ST_Transform(geometry, crs_id)**

You should also check the geometry type for your **geo_data.geom** field, for example in PgAdmin3.

For example,

- if the type is geometry(Polygon, 32717) it's in your UTM projection
- of it's geometry(Polygon, 4326) it's in wgs84 (lat/lon)
- if it's geometry(Polygon, 0) it's undefined. If so you'll need to set it using **st_setsrid(geometry, crs_id)**. This can happen if you use shp2pgsql and forget to set the srid. I do this all the time :)

> For the query to work, the polygon and point geometries need to be in the same crs.

If your polygons ARE in 32717 this should work

```
select 
    * 
from 
    geo_data
where 
    st_contains(
        geom, 
        ST_Transform(   
            ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-78.480439 -0.179156)',4326),
            32717
        )
    )
```